# Append list elements to the sublists of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

`l1 = [[1, ['A', 'B'], 2], [3, ['D', 'E'], 4]]`

&

`l2 = ['C', 'F']`

I'm having trouble appending the `l2` elements to each `sublist[1]` so that I can get:

`l3 = [[1, ['A', 'B', 'C'], 2], [3, ['D', 'E', 'F'], 4]]`

I think I am just slightly off, but the `append()` method I keep trying is not working.

Comment: Post code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.append` is the right way to go. Are you appending to the correct sublist? Here's one way using a loop.

```
In [702]: for i, l in enumerate(l1):
     ...:     l[1].append(l2[i])
     ...:     

In [703]: l1
Out[703]: [[1, ['A', 'B', 'C'], 2], [3, ['D', 'E', 'F'], 4]]
```

There's probably other ways to do this, but this is the simplest.

Comment: So, did the OP show their code? Can't see it anywhere.

Comment: @vaultah Touche...  but they said they had done something with `.append`, which I didn't read at first ;-)

Comment: My `.append()` method was trying to leverage list comprehension to create an updated list. While I tried to be pythonic, in this case I don't think it would've worked and yours did perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

l1[0][1].insert(len(l1[0][1]), l2[0])

You can probably do it with append also, but this works just the same.
It is slower. If you are worried about performance, don't use this. But for trivial tasks, it looks nice.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html